# With TypeORM getManyWithCount how to generate a PageInfo for pagination

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, relay, typeorm

I am implementing a Relay style pagination for a GraphQL server, and using the excellent TypeORM library.

I want to find the best way to create a PageInfo object after a query:

```
type PageInfo {
  endCursor: String
  hasNextPage: Boolean!
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean!
  startCursor: String
}
```

```
if (before) {
  qb = qb.andWhere('note.notedAt <=(:before)', { before });
}

if (after) {
  qb = qb.andWhere('note.notedAt >(:after)', { after });
}

qb = qb.take(args.take)
const [entities, totalEntitesCount] = qb.getManyWithCount()
```

So with this info how do we calculate `hasNextPage` and `hasPreviousPage`

My current thinking:

```
function createPageInfo(
  noteEdges: Array<{ node: Note; cursor: Date }>,
  totalCount: number,
  findOptions: NoteFindOptions
) {

  let hasNextPage: boolean;
  let hasPreviousPage: boolean;

  if(findOptions.after) {
    hasPreviousPage = true;
    hasNextPage = (noteEdges.length < totalCount)
  } else if (findOptions.before) {
    hasNextPage = true;
    hasPreviousPage = (noteEdges.length < totalCount)
  } else {
    hasPreviousPage = false;
    hasNextPage = (noteEdges.length < totalCount)
  }

  return {
    startCursor: noteEdges[0].cursor,
    endCursor: noteEdges[noteEdges.length - 1].cursor,
    hasNextPage,
    hasPreviousPage
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will pretty much work, but keep in mind that `totalEntitiesCount` is not count of all entries in the table but only of those that match your cursor condition (`note.notedAt > :after` or `note.notedAt <= :before`). `gb.getManyAndCount()` internally removes any orderBy, limit, skip, etc. but keeps where conditions (see [this file](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/query-builder/SelectQueryBuilder.ts#L1728)).

Also IDK if relaying on `before` / `after` cursor to determine `hasNext` / `hasPrev` respectively is ok. If you'd pass first ID or date in the table to the `after` cursor you'd still get `hasPreviousPage = true` but in fact there would be none.

You can see my take on this in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/VojtaSim/6b03466f1964a6c81a3dbf1f8cec8d5c). The idea is to query results first and then create count query for totalCount and items before and after the results. Count query is cloned before applying where conditions. This allows to keep any previous conditions but avoid cursor condition. As a bonus you'll get count of next/prev items.

It's still WIP, I haven't tested it yet.